# ParallelStream with filter chaining

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, filtering

Does `filter` chaining change the outcome if i use `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()` ?

I tried with a few thousand records, and the output appeared consistent over a few iterations. But since this involves threads,(and I could not find enough relevant material that talks about this combination) I want to make doubly sure that parallel stream does not impact the output of filter chaining in any way. Example code:

```
List<Element> list = myList.parallelStream()
      .filter(element -> element.getId() > 10)
      .filter(element -> element.getName().contains("something"))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

The `filter` operation as documented expects a [non-interferening](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) and [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) predicate to apply to each element to determine if it should be included as part of the new stream.

Few aspects that you shall consider for that are -

1. With an exception to concurrent collections(what do you choose as  `myList` in the existing code to be) -

> For most data sources, preventing interference means ensuring that the
> data source is not modified at all during the execution of the stream
> pipeline.

2. The state of the data sources (`myList` and its `element`s within your filter operations are not mutated)

> Note also that attempting to access mutable state from behavioral
> parameters presents you with a bad choice with respect to safety and
> performance;

Moreover, think around it, what is it in your `filter` operation that would be impacted by multiple threads. Given the current code, nothing functionally, as long as both the operations are executed, you would get a consistent result regardless of the thread(s) executing them.

Comment: It’s worth noting that, assuming `getId()` and `getName()` are trivial getters, the OP’s predicates fulfill the constraints. The predicates could be evaluated for different elements of the source list at the same time. Still, it is guaranteed that the second predicate will never get evaluated for an element that didn’t pass the first predicate. For the OP’s example, not even that matters, but imagine an example like `.filter(x -> x != null) .filter(x -> x.getSomeProperty().equals(y))`. For that example, `x.getSomeProperty()` can not fail for `x` being `null`, due to the first predicate.